# JPA ManyToMany relationship with unique attribute

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a ManyToMany relationship from a class called Card to a class called Color. I am using JPA and Hibernate.

Card.java

```
@Entity(name = "Cards")
public class Card
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "card_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long cardId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Color> colors;
}
```

Color.java

```
@Entity(name = "Colors")
public class Color
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long colorId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

But if I am persisting a Card java throws an exception, because Black is already contained in Colors.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Black' for key 'UK_sd7tby3rtx8snv2vlbmlmy69o'
```

But I want Colors.name to be unique and JPA should search Colors if the color is already persisted and use the persisted color.

Comment: JPA will not "search Colors if color is already persisted", that is your job. JPA is there to persist what you give it

Comment: Oh ok. Did not know this fact :/

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm starting to think the only good way around this is to manually create your join table as an Entity, using two OneToMany relationships, and use Hibernate's event system to do the unique checking/fixing manually, which is unfortunate

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you need `OneToMany` relation and add new filed to `Color` class, like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "card")
private List<Color> colors;

//Add to `Color`class
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "card_id", nullable = false)
private Card card;
```

Comment: I did not mention it, but a card can have more colors. The context are magic cards. I don't know, if you know them :)